# Why different line endings - Unix vs Windows

Tags: windows, unix

Just out of curiousity.. Why are the line endings different for Windows and Unix. 
I was looking around for the answer but not found.

Answer (score 3):

because:

> ASCII was developed simultaneously by
>   the ISO and the ASA

via: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History

Comment: The rest of that Wikipedia section details the rather more practical and boring consequences from the origins of each operating system;  Unix conventions are taken from Multics and Windows from MS-DOS which in turn took its convention from CP/M.  To quote: "CP/M's use of CR+LF made sense for using computer terminals via serial lines." - Wikipedia.

Comment: In-band signaling is a horrendous thing.